# VC++ Code Build in VS2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, build, mfc, legacy-code

I am trying to build VC++ legacy code in VS2013. Initially I was not able to build the code because  of error :

> error MSB8031: Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set
>   is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or
>   download an additional library.

For resolving this issue I have changed the following settings:
Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Project Default->Character Set  ->Use Unicode Character Set.

This has resolved my problem of building the code where as I started recieving errors inappropraite Type Casting error for all my message boxes and for other User defined strings:
Sample Code for MessageBox:

```
MessageBox (NULL, "Some String","Some String", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
```

> Error: error C2664: 'int MessageBoxW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,UINT)' :
>   cannot convert argument 2 from 'String' to 'LPCWSTR'.

It was all working for VS2010.

Is there any setting I can turn on or off in VS2013 so that I should not recieve such type casting or Do I have to manually type cast for every error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the project to use Unicode, so you need to have wide char strings as your literals. With MFC, you can use the `_T()` macro to automatically do the correct thing based on your project settings.

For your example, try this:

```
MessageBox (NULL, _T("Some String"), _T("Some String"), MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
```

On a Unicode build, the macro will expand to make the literals wide chars:

```
MessageBox (NULL, L"Some String", L"Some String", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
```

The `_T()` macro is identical to the `_TEXT` macro and these and other Unicode tips are [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx).

If you have too much code to convert everything to Unicode (it's not trivial), you may wish to carry on using MBCS, [which it is possible to do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/08/mfc-support-for-mbcs-deprecated-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) by downloading the optional [Multibyte Library for VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40770) and changing your project properties back to the way they were originally.

Comment: Thanks,I downloaded Multibyte Character Set Library for MFC and installed it. It worked. Manky Thanks again